# How would I determine when $\sin(100) < 1$ to test for convergency of this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

My Stewart calculus textbook gives the following problem and asks to determine if the series converges or diverges, and to find the sum if it converges: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (\sin(100))^k$

Now, I know that this is a geometric series and that it will converge for when $|r| < 1$. But what I don't understand is how to determine whether $\sin(100) < 1$ without using a calculator.

Comment: $|\sin(x)| = 1$ only when $x = \pm\frac{\pi}{2},\pm\frac{3\pi}{2},\pm\frac{5\pi}{2},\ldots$. You just need to show that $100$ cannot be written on this form.

Comment: I'm assuming 100 is in radians; the book doesn't specify

Comment: It's $<1$ even if $100$ is in degrees. To show this use that $100^\circ = \frac{2\pi}{360}\cdot 100 = \frac{5\pi}{9}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|\sin (x)|=1$ if $x$ is an odd multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Suppose on the contradiction that $$|sin(100)|=1$$ Then we can conclude that $$100=k\frac{\pi}{2}$$

where $k$ is an odd integer.

Then $\pi=\frac{200}{k}$ but $\pi$ is irrational but $\frac{200}{k}$ is rational, hence we get a contradiction. $$|\sin(100)|<1.$$

and we have $$\sin(100)<1$$

The above working is for $100$ being interpreted as radian.

Suppose it is in degree, well, $100$ is not a multiple of $90$.

Comment: I hate that I'm this far in mathematics and that I still get tripped up by simple things like this. What's the significance of pi being irrational?

Comment: I made a typo just now. I meant to type $\pi=\frac{200}{k}$.

Comment: The left hand side is irrational but the right hand side is rational, hence we get a contradiction, Hence our initial assumption must be wrong.

Comment: I see. So how would I determine whether sin of this angle is < 1? I'm sorry if this seems like a stupid question or if I'm going in circles, but I'm legitimately confused. If the angle were written in terms of pi, then I would have less trouble.

Comment: |sin(angle)| is equal to  $1$ if and only if it is an odd multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: @AleksandrH Since $\pi$ is irrational, no integer is an integer multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$, so $|\sin(n)| \neq 1$ for integer $n$.

Comment: In fact, $|\sin(q)| \neq 1\forall q \in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: I'm so stupid, I just realized that if sin(100) is never 1, then it is always less than 1, and so it must converge. Urgh, hate calculus. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sin(100)=1$, then $100$ would be an integer multiple of $\pi/2$.
That is, 
$$
\frac{200}{\pi}
$$
would have to be an integer.

Calculating, we find $\frac{200}{\pi} \approx 63.661... $ so it appears not to be an integer.  Proving this requires bounds on $\pi$.

If we are willing to accept that
$$
3.14 < \pi < 3.142
$$
then we may conclude that
$$
63.65372374... < \frac{200}{\pi} < 63.694267515...
$$
and since there is no integer between these two bounds, we know $\frac{200}{\pi}$ is not an integer, and hence $\sin(100) \neq 1$.